# Cerrar ventana de popup

Tags: html, css, angular

Estoy trabajando un proyecto simple de angular y he realizado un popup, en el cual al pulsar un botón referente a un producto, pues salga la descripción, imagen y nombre del mismo. Dentro de este contenededor del producto, he creado un botón nuevo, uno que simula la cruceta de una ventana para que esta sea cerrada.

He conseguido que el botón reaccione con el evento click, sin embargo no logro intuir o deducir cómo hacer que el botón funcione para que ÚNICAMENTE me cierre la ventana concreta en la que está, es decir, que si abro el producto "movil", pues al pulsar la cruceta del móvil, me lo cierre

movil.component.html

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <button class="boton_cerrar" (click)="closeMovil()">X</button>
  <p><u>Nombre:</u></p> {{nombre}}
  <p><u>descripción:</u></p> {{descripcion}}
  <p><u>Imagen:</u></p>
  <img src="{{imagen}}" alt="imagen de movil" class="imagen-movil">
</div>
```

movil.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwitchService } from 'src/app/service/switch.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movil',
  templateUrl: './movil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movil.component.css']
})
export class MovilComponent implements OnInit {

  nombre = 'Nokia 3310';
  descripcion = 'Movil Nokia 3310 listo para comprar a un precio bastante economico.';
  imagen = '../../../assets/img/movil.JPG';

  closeMovil()
  {
    this.modalSS.$modalMovil.emit(false)
    console.log("Boton cerrar movil funciona correctamente");
  }

  constructor(private modalSS: SwitchService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

modal.component.html

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal_body">
    <button class="boton_cerrar" (click)="closeModal()">X</button>
    <div class="productos_tienda">
      <button class="boton-Movil" (click)="openMovil()">Movil</button>
      <div class="" *ngIf="modalMovil == true">
        <app-movil></app-movil>
      </div>
      <button class="boton-Bberry" (click)="openBlackberry()">Blackberry</button>
      <div class="" *ngIf="modalBlackBerry == true">
        <app-blackberry></app-blackberry>
      </div>
      <button class="boton-Vinilo" (click)="openVinilo()">Disco de Vinilo</button>
      <div class="" *ngIf="modalVinilo == true">
        <app-vinilo></app-vinilo>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwitchService } from '../service/switch.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.css']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  modalMovil!: boolean;
  modalBlackBerry!: boolean;
  modalVinilo!: boolean;

  constructor(private modalSS: SwitchService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  closeModal()
  {
    this.modalSS.$modal.emit(false)
    console.log("Boton cerrar modal funciona correctamente");
  }

  openMovil()
  {
    this.modalMovil = true;
    console.log("Movil funciona correctamente");
  }

  openBlackberry()
  {
    this.modalBlackBerry = true;
    console.log("Blackberry funciona correctamente");
  }

  openVinilo()
  {
    this.modalVinilo = true;
    console.log("Vinilo funciona correctamente");
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="contenido-pop">
  <img
    src="../assets/img/corteingles.png"
    alt="logo corte ingles"
    class="logo-corteingles"
  />
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h2><u>¡Bienvenido a la tienda!</u></h2>
    <div class="fondo-pop">
      <button class="boton-abrir" (click)="openModal()">Abrir modal</button>
      <div class="" *ngIf="modalSwitch == true">
        <app-modal></app-modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <img src="../assets/img/letracorteingles.png" alt="tipografia corte ingles" class="letra-corteingles">
  </footer>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwitchService } from './service/switch.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'popup_anguloso';

  modalSwitch!: boolean;

  constructor(private modalSS:SwitchService){
  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.modalSS.$modal.subscribe((valor)=>{this.modalSwitch = valor})
  }

  openModal()
  {
    this.modalSwitch = true;
  }
}
```

Switch.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SwitchService {
  constructor() { }

  $modal = new EventEmitter<any>();
  $modalMovil = new EventEmitter<any>();
  $modalBlackBerry = new EventEmitter<any>();
  $modalVinilo = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Comment: Según veo agregaste el código del popup del producto, creo que también seria necesario que agregues el código donde abres este popup. ;)

Comment: Tienes razón :)! Listo, ya esta añadido todo lo necesario para su comprensión

Comment: Acabo de darle una mirada a tu código y tengo una pregunta, ¿El componente **`modal.component.ts`** funciona correctamente al presionar el botón cerrar?

Comment: Si, funciona correctamente. Los que no funcionan/no consigo establecer para que funcionen son los de los productos.

Comment: Aunque bueno si vamos directo al grano, lo que podrías hacer según la lógica que utilizas según veo es reutilizar el servicio que tienes `SwitchService` para crear una nueva variable similar a la que tienes `$modal`, supongamos llamarlo `$modalMovil` y en tu componente **movil** utilizarlo en lugar de `$modal` ya que veo que en el constructor también instancias el servicio por lo que no será problema, debes hacer lo mismo que haces en tu componente `modal.component.ts`, solo ahora utilizando `$modalMovil` en lugar de `$modal`

Comment: Buenas, he intentado hacer lo que dices, he creado las variables respectivas para los productos y he hecho el close, sin embargo, no me los cierra, he añadido el script de switch.service.ts y el modificado del movil.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en lo que tienes hecho.

Según comentas el popup *modal* funciona correctamente, entonces lo que podemos hacer es aplicar lo mismo que hiciste, en este caso ya tienes la mayor parte hecha solo te falta la parte donde se escucha el cambio de valor de la variable `$modalMovil`.

En el OnInit() del archivo **`modal.component.ts`**:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // Esto es para escuchar el evento (Cuando se ejecute el .emiter(false) que haces desde el componente movil.component)
  this.modalSS.$modalMovil.subscribe(valor => this.modalMovil = valor);
}
```

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, soy nuevo en esto de Angular y estoy aprendiendo, me ha funcionado :)!